# Does a Markov process have memory zero?

Tags: statistics, markov-chains, statistical-inference, markov-process

I have the following question:

> The Markov process with two states and a transition matrix $$P =\begin{pmatrix} 0.3 & 0.7 \\ 0.3 & 0.7 \end{pmatrix}$$ 
>   has memory zero. Is it true?

My guess is that (this?) Markov process has memory $1$ because to predict for example something for the next step we can use the matrix $P$ which I suppose describes the process with two states. Am I correct? Could you please give me a better explanation of why a Markov process has memory $0$ or $1$ (or more eventually)?

Comment: What's your definition of memory, exactly? Is it the number $k$ such that you know the distribution of $X_n$ if and only if you know the distribution of $X_{n-1},X_{n-2},\dots,X_{n-k}$? If so, then the memory of any discrete time Markov chain is $1$, except perhaps in very boring cases where it could be $0$. This is not one of those boring cases.

Comment: Actually sorry, I made a mistake: this *is* one of those boring cases. No matter what initial distribution you start with, the distribution after one step will be $(0.3,0.7)$.

Comment: Do the multiplication: assume $p=(p_1,p_2),p_1+p_2=1$ and multiply out $pP$. You should get $(0.3,0.7)$.

Comment: It's not because $p_1+p_2=1$ so much as because both rows are the same. Look at what happens when the rows are different.

Comment: When all rows of the P matrix are identical, it is an iid process.